# Using jquery to initiate custom events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm attempting to use an audio player on my site and I need to use jquery to make an image act as a play/pause button.

Currently I'm using JS and CSS image sprites to make the image change when its clicked. So to begin with the image is displayed as a play button, when it's clicked the first time it becomes a pause button. Then if its clicked again it becomes a play button etc.

The first time its clicked it plays the track in the audio player, however if clicked again it wont pause it.

Ideally I need to make it so when the button is clicked it will play the track and then pause it if clicked again.

The audio player comes with custom events which I believe can be used to achieve what I'm after but I'm not too sure how to implement the play and pause event.

The custom event can be found here:
http://radykal.de/codecanyon/fullwidthaudioplayer/#api

Below is the current JS and CSS I'm using.

JS

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".fap-single-track").click(function() {
      jQuery(this).toggleClass('playing');
   });
});
  </script>
```

CSS

```
.fap-single-track {
display: block;
width: 24px;
height: 23px;
text-indent: -99999px;
background: url(http://www.danceyrselfclean.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/sprites.png);
cursor: pointer;
}

.playing{
background-position: -27px 0;
}

.playing:hover {
background-position: -27px -28px !important;
}

.play_pause:hover {
background-position: 0 -28px;
}
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please choose a les generic title

Comment: Ok I've changed it to be a little less generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you gave, you have to use **.toggle()** and not **.toggleClass**

Answer (score 1):

I got there in the end with a little help. I just had to add in the custom event in the correct place so the JS now looks like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".fap-single-track").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('playing');
  jQuery.fullwidthAudioPlayer.toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks yeah I wasn’t sure if you were referring to the toggleClass('playing') part though.

Comment: Cheers! sorry, i focused only on the play / toggle question that you put. Didnt look at the css part